# Analogue for sql join in jq

Tags: shell, unix, jq

I have the following json:

```
[
  {"id": "1", "type": "folder", "title": "folder-1"},
  {"id": "2", "type": "folder", "title": "folder-2"},
  {"id": "3", "type": "item", "title": "item-1", "folder": "1"},
  {"id": "4", "type": "item", "title": "item-2", "folder": "2"},
  {"id": "5", "type": "item", "title": "item-3"}
]
```

Basically, I need to produce this output using jq, which is similar to the result of sql join:

```
[
  {"type": "item", "title": "item-1", "folder": "folder-1"},
  {"type": "item", "title": "item-2", "folder": "folder-2"},
  {"type": "item", "title": "item-3"}
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't even look like json. What type of json is that? Try `jq . file`.

Comment: @konsolebox, I corrected the json. Now `jq '.' file` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this filter:

```
map(
    (select(.type=="item") | { key: .folder, value: { type, title } }),
    (select(.type=="folder") | { key: .id, value: { folder: .title } })
)
| group_by(.key)
| map(
    (map(select(.key != null) | .value) | add)
    // map(.value)[]
)
```

You'll have to break this out into steps.

1. Get the items and folders and for each, take the values you're interested in and assign it a key to associate with.

   ```
   map(
       (select(.type=="item") | { key: .folder, value: { type, title } }),
       (select(.type=="folder") | { key: .id, value: { folder: .title } })
   )
   ```
2. Group all by the key

   ```
   | group_by(.key)
   ```
3. Then combine the values that have keys (folders) and the value otherwise

   ```
   | map(
       (map(select(.key != null) | .value) | add)
       // map(.value)[]
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
jq 'map(select(has("folder") or (.["title"] | startswith("item"))) | del(.id))' sample_file
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "type": "item",
    "title": "item-1",
    "folder": "1"
  },
  {
    "type": "item",
    "title": "item-2",
    "folder": "2"
  },
  {
    "type": "item",
    "title": "item-3"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not exactly the solution but it's a start. The added difficulty lies in the fact that you have to store preceding data to merge with it but I'm not sure if `jq` allows it.

Comment: I need the title of the folders, not their ids.

Comment: @YuryOparin Yes that's the difficult part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which works by separating the data into two objects `$folders` and `$items` and then constructing the desired result.

```
  (
    reduce map(select(.type == "folder"))[] as $f (
      {}
    ; .[$f.id] = $f
    )
  ) as $folders

| (
    reduce map(select(.type == "item"))[] as $i (
      {}
    ; .[$i.id] = $i
    ) 
  ) as $items

| [
      $items[]
    | {type, title, folder}
    | if .folder == null then del(.folder) else .folder = $folders[.folder].title end
  ]
```

If your version of jq has [INDEX/2](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L294-L299)

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
```

this can be simplified to

```
  INDEX(.[] | select(.type == "folder"); .id) as $folders
| INDEX(.[] | select(.type == "item"); .id) as $items
| [
      $items[]
    | {type, title, folder}
    | if .folder == null then del(.folder) else .folder = $folders[.folder].title end
  ]
```