# Using SQL-style JOIN operator with jq

Tags: json, left-join, jq

I'd like to use `jq` to do a left join on these two objects in an array by using the `jq` JOIN operator:

```
[
  {
    "type": "spreadsheet",
    "rows": [
      [
        "1",
        "Ben",
        "male"
      ],
      [
        "2",
        "Cathy",
        "female"
      ]
    ],
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "sex"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "spreadsheet",
    "rows": [
      [
        "1",
        "25"
      ],
      [
        "2",
        "28"
      ]
    ],
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "age"
    ]
  }
]
```

to this:

```
{
    "type": "spreadsheet",
    "rows": [
      [
        "1",
        "Ben",
        "male",
        "25"
      ],
      [
        "2",
        "Cathy",
        "female",
        "28"
      ]
    ],
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "sex",
      "age"
    ]
}
```

The [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) references SQL-style operators like `INDEX` and `JOIN` but I can't find any examples online of how to use them. Like any join, I need to iterate over the rows in the first object and merge with rows found in the second object based on the `id` column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analogue for sql join in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131293/analogue-for-sql-join-in-jq)

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify why it's not a duplicate: the other question's answers make no mention of `jq`'s SQL-style operators.

Comment: Noting that SQL-style were implemented at [this commit](https://github.com/nicowilliams/jq/commit/3726007bdd9e2fbd64b59b529d58c95cdb767178#diff-b74863ae6880e7cc09f2e3f38da9ebd5), which shows the equivalent native construction. A few lines down from that, you'll see a test case demonstrating the use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following adopts an object-oriented approach to the task, and ignores keys other than "rows" and "columns" in the input.

There are accordingly three steps:

1. convert the tabular (columns/rows) representation of the "database" to an OO representation -- this is accomplished by `toOO`;
2. perform the update -- accomplished by `left_join`;
3. convert the OO representation back to the tabular form (`toDB`)

The main program is thus quite short:

```
map(toOO) | left_join(.id) | toDB
```

The helper functions, most of which are independently useful, are presented below but should appear before the main program above.

#### Helper Functions

```
# headers should be an array of strings
def objectify(headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i ({};
      . + {(headers[$i]): $in[$i]} );

def fromObject:
  . as $in
  | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ( {rows:[], columns:[]};
     .columns += [$k] | .rows += [$in[$k]] );

# Input: an array of object
# Output: a single object with array-valued keys formed from
# the input object by (blindly) concatenating the values
def merge:
  def allkeys: map(keys) | add | unique;
  allkeys as $allkeys
  | reduce .[] as $in ({};
     reduce $allkeys[] as $k (.;
      . + {($k): (.[$k] + [$in[$k]]) } ));

# id should be a filter such as .id
# Apply merge but do not replicate id
def merge_by(id):
  merge | (id |= .[0] ) ;

# Create an object-representation of the columns/rows database
def toOO:
  .columns as $headers
  | [.rows[] | objectify($headers)];

def toDB:
  map(fromObject)
  | merge_by(.columns);

# Input: an array of two arrays, each consisting of objects forming a database.
# "key" specifies the (possibly composite) key to be used to form the
# left-join of the two databases. 
# That is, objects are NOT added to the first database.
def left_join(key):
  def updateObject(obj):
    reduce .[] as $x ([];
      if ($x|key) == (obj|key) 
      then . + [$x + obj] else . + [$x]
      end);
  reduce .[1][] as $x (.[0]; updateObject($x) );
```

#### Output

```
{
  "columns": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "sex",
    "age"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "1",
      "Ben",
      "male",
      "25"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "Cathy",
      "female",
      "28"
    ]
  ]
}
```

#### Using `JOIN` builtin

If your jq has `JOIN/4`, then it can be used to implement `left_join/1` as follows:

```
def left_join(key):
  map(INDEX(key)) 
  | [ JOIN( .[1]; .[0][]; key; add) ] ;
```

In theory, this should be more efficient than the definition given above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "If your jq has `JOIN/4`". What does the `/4` mean, and how can I tell if my jq has it?

Comment: The number is the arity, and you can tell in a number of ways: checking the jq documentation corresponding to the version of jq you are using; checking the output of `builtins` (available in jq 1.5 and later); or attempting to use it, e.g. by running `jq -n 'JOIN(0;0;0;0)'`.